# how to predict query topics using word-topic matrix?

Tags: lda, topic-modeling, unsupervised-learning

I'm implementing LDA using Java. I know how the algorithm works. In the end of the training (the given iterations) I will get 2 matrices (topic-word and document-topic) that represent the set of the input documents.

My problem is that when I input a new document (query) I want to use these matrices (or any other way) to get the document-topic vector of that query. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Variational Inference or Gibbs Sampling?

For Gibbs Sampling a typical approach is adding the new document/s to the inference, and only updating its own counters, keeping constant the counters for the documents you used to learn the model.

This is specified in equations 84 and 85 in [Parameter Estimation for Text Analysis](http://www.arbylon.net/publications/text-est.pdf)

I guess there has to be a similar approach in VI LDA.